# c++: why the restriction on offsetof() for non-standard layout objects, or how to recover parent from pointer-to-member

Tags: c++, pointers, c++17, c++20

I have a situation where I have a pointer to a data member, and from that, wish to recover the address of the containing object (implementing 'properties' class for an object).

I have a fully functional implementation https://onlinegdb.com/ByQJurll_

- convert the ptr-to-member to an offset
- subtract back to get the parent
- be careful to static_cast<> appropriately to handle multiple inheritance

But as near as I can tell, this code is not portable, well defined C++, when applied to a container object that uses public/private.

This is because from what I understand, the offsetof() trick is only guaranteed to work for standard_layout<> objects, and if you use public/private, it is no longer considered standard_layout.

I cannot understand the motivation behind this restriction (especially since what I have already works on many compilers - all tested). Is there some portable, legal way in C++ to recover the containing object given a pointer to member, and the address of that member?

(code is all in that link above, but quick summary here)

```
    template < typename OUTER_OBJECT, typename DATA_MEMBER_TYPE >
      inline size_t
    ConvertPointerToDataMemberToOffset (DATA_MEMBER_TYPE
                        (OUTER_OBJECT::*dataMember))
    {
instance
      return reinterpret_cast <
        char *>(&(((OUTER_OBJECT *) 0)->*dataMember)) - reinterpret_cast <
        char *>(0);
    }
    
    template < typename APPARENT_MEMBER_TYPE, typename OUTER_OBJECT,
      typename AGGREGATED_OBJECT_TYPE >
      inline OUTER_OBJECT * GetObjectOwningField (APPARENT_MEMBER_TYPE *
                              aggregatedMember,
                              AGGREGATED_OBJECT_TYPE
                              (OUTER_OBJECT::
                               *aggregatedPtrToMember))
    {
      std::byte * adjustedAggregatedMember =
        reinterpret_cast < std::byte * >(static_cast <
                         AGGREGATED_OBJECT_TYPE *
                         >(aggregatedMember));
      ptrdiff_t adjustment =
        static_cast < ptrdiff_t >
        (ConvertPointerToDataMemberToOffset (aggregatedPtrToMember));
      return reinterpret_cast <
        OUTER_OBJECT * >(adjustedAggregatedMember - adjustment);
    }
    void DoTest ();
    struct X1
    {
      int a;
      int b;
    };
    struct X2
    {
    public:
      int a;
    private:
      int b;
    private:
        friend void DoTest ();
    };
    void
    DoTest ()
    {
      {
        X1 t;
        static_assert (is_standard_layout_v < X1 >);
        void *aAddr = &t.a;
        void *bAddr = &t.b;
        assert (GetObjectOwningField (aAddr, &X1::a) == &t);
        assert (GetObjectOwningField (bAddr, &X1::b) == &t);
      }
      {
        // Check and warning but since X2 is not standard layout, this isn't guaranteed to work
        X2 t;
        static_assert (not is_standard_layout_v < X2 >);
        void *aAddr = &t.a;
        void *bAddr = &t.b;
        assert (GetObjectOwningField (aAddr, &X2::a) == &t);
        assert (GetObjectOwningField (bAddr, &X2::b) == &t);
      }
    }
```

Comment: I believe `offsetof` is by itself not portable. Compilers don't have to support it.

Comment: According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof - its implementation defined, but its part of the C++ standard. Besides, that doesn't help. I'm looking to do BETTER than the c++ standard appears to guarantee, but in a portable safe way, or understand why this is omitted by the c++ standard.

Comment: The language does not support what you are trying to do. Even using `offsetof`, I don't think it allows `reinterpret_cast<OUTER_OBJECT * >(adjustedAggregatedMember - adjustment)`. The only fully defined way I can think of to use `offsetof` is with `memcpy`. There are restrictions on what arithmetic operations you are allowed to perform on a pointer, and I don't believe deriving an object from a pointer to a data member is one of those operations.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux AFAIK, pointer arithmetic is undefined if the pointers don't point to elements within an array. And an object is not considered an array of `unsigned char` or `std::byte`... yet; I think there's a proposal for that, but last I checked it wasn't accepted yet.

Comment: @underscore_d That is correct, but standard layout objects have special rules that you can convert between pointer to the first member with pointers to the object. And there may be other sneaky rules related to that, so I am not confident in saying that it is definitely not possible.

Comment: @lewis> What exactly is the point of asking why? Understanding the motivation will not fix your code. What you want is not possible, and I do not even understand the *goal* of doing so, as even if getting such a pointer was possible, using it would still be illegal.

Comment: High level question -- are you trying to emulate how another computer language handles these situations? If so, it usually is not wise to try and model C++ in looking like another computer language.

Comment: What you have works **for simple cases**. Now consider a derived class that has  a virtual base. Figure out how to get back to the derived type from a pointer-to-member of that base class. Keep in mind that you cannot determine the offset from the derived object to the base object at compile time, because the derived type may be a base class of a further derived type with the same virtual base. A pointer-to-member has to carry around more information than just an offset. That's why they're not called pointers.

Comment: @spectras you asked WHY I want this? I alluded to why, but let me be more explicit. I program alot in C#, and really like the property getter/setter feature. I've implemented this (and it FULLY FUNCTIONS JUST AS I WANT). BUT - it leverages this offseting above which is apparently strictly not legal C++. And I want to figure out how to make it legal C++. Here is a poitner to the docs page (header) for the PROPERTIES implementation that uses the above:  https://github.com/SophistSolutions/Stroika/blob/v2.1-Dev/Library/Sources/Stroika/Foundation/Common/Property.h#L169

Comment: @PeteBecker I realized (but should have more carefully documented) that what I have doesn't work for virtual base classes. But for my use case, (properties) - it doesn't need to. Though I would obviously prefer a mechansim that was more offcially blessed (and thats the point of the question).

Comment: I THINK one of the justifications for leaving property 'getter'/'setter' feature out of C++ was probably that you could impement such logic in your own classes. But I've found several property classes, none that worked very well. With this trick of FINDING the parent class, my Property <> mechamism works quite simply and well; I just want to find a way to have that implementation 'keep kosher' ;-)

Comment: @PeteBecker are there OTHER cases where what I'm doing wont work besides virtual base classes? I have tried it (successfully) with multiple inheritance, and that seems to work fine.

Comment: Making that legal invalidates a host of optimizations. It's unlikely to happen without a _really_ good reason.

Comment: @T.C.Could you kindly elaborate on (at least one or two interesting) optimizations that are precluded by allowing one to recover the aggregating object address from a pointer to one of its data members?

Comment: Currently, if I pass a pointer/reference to a data member of a class to some function, the compiler can generally assume that *other* data members of the class are not changed by the call (with some exceptions) because there is no valid way to go from a member to the full class. That assumption doesn't hold if you can recover a valid pointer to the full class from the pointer to a data member.

Comment: @T.C. How would that work with threads? It doesn't appear on the surface that it could. And how would it be useful to know the other data members didn't change unless you wanted to use their cached values. But I cannot see how that would be useful unless you referenced those fields.

Comment: I DO have a good reason (maybe you will disagree about it being a really good reason). I really LIKE the syntax of properties (from C#). The conventional C++ pattern of writing o->GetXXX(), o->SetXXX (v) methods is clearly more (and nesslessly) verbose compared to obj->xxx, and obj->xxx = v; If you want to implement properties in a class library, you need to somehow access that containing object this variable. You CAN do it with a lambda capture, or by the address arithmatic trick. Both are equally simple to do, but the this binding approach needlessly adds alot of code bloat (this bindings).

Comment: @PeteBecker in response to your point about virtual base classes, I can accept that in SOME cases you may not be able to have offsetof() work properly. But the restriction that it only works for 'standard-layout' classes is (as near as I'm able to understand) needlessly strong. For example, I don't see why declaring a field as private, or adding a virtual function (which makes the class not standard-layout) should make offsetof() harder to implement.